# remove static varialble android service

Tags: android, sqlite, android-service

There is android  application  which  stored  data  into the sqlite. I keep a list of routes in databases table.I display the data on the active route on the screen/To release the processor, I use static List inside service.To release the processor, I use static List inside service. I change the list when receiving data from the server.

```
public class NetworkService extends Service{

    private static NetworkService instance = null;

    private static List<RouteTask> routeTaskList;
    private static LoadRoutesTask loadRoutesTask;

    private static RouteChangedListener rtListener ;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this;

            NetworkManager.updateNetworkInfo(this);
            NetworkManager.setNetworkListener(this);    
        }
    }   

    public static Context getCurrentContext() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static boolean hasInstance() {
        return instance != null;
    }   

    public static void setRouteTaskList(List<RouteTask> rtList)
    {       
        routeTaskList = rtList ;        
    }

    public static List<RouteTask> getRouteTask(){
        return routeTaskList;
    }

}
```

In application i can set value

```
NetworkService.setRouteTaskList(list);
```

or get value :

```
 List<RouteTask>  = NetworkService.getRouteTaskList();
```

My application usually use routeTaskList instead of sql query for data table.

The task now is change the service, for the android development standards. I removed static field and Now, I run a service through intents (startService(intent)).  How Can I remove static  settter and getter for routeTaskList object ?

Comment: Remove the `static` property from the variable `routeTaskList` and remove the `static` property from the setter/getter for it. Now, you can instantiate a `new NetworkService()` object and call the getter and setter on your object

Comment: but i have to  start service several time. static object is one for instance. after statService it will have another object

Comment: @j.seashell You absolutely positively cannot instantiate an Android `Service` using `new`. Only the Android framework can instantiate Android components!

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the `Service` with the list of tasks as extras in the `Intent` you use in the `startService()` call. This replaces your static setter.

To get the list of tasks is more complicated. Options:

1. You could use AIDL and bind to the `Service` and then call a method to get the list of tasks
2. You could call `startService()` with an `Intent` that asks the `Service` to broadcast the list of tasks. In the `Service.onStartCommand()` you could then send a broadcast `Intent` which contains the list of tasks as extras.
3. You could have the `Service` send a **sticky** broadcast `Intent` which contains the list of tasks every time the list changes. Your app would then use `registerReceiver()` call to read the most recently sent sticky broadcast.